# Integrated terminal VSCode not showing runtime after running C++ code

Tags: c++, terminal, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am using code-runner to run C++ in VSCode. When I show the output in OUTPUT, it shows running time or allows me to know if there is any runtime error or not.

[In OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Dj5.png)

But when I show the output in Integrated Terminal, it does not show any runtime.

[Integrated Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dXLC.png)

Please Note: I need to use Integrated Terminal because OUTPUT does not allow me to edit (it's Read-Only).

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: The "run-time" is part of VSCode's own execution system, it's not part of the terminal.

Comment: So, I explicitly need to add some code to know my runtime while using terminal, right? Or, is there any alternative?